# Unrecognized SSL Certificate in K9 mail

Tags: ssl, genymotion, k-9mail

I'm trying to send secure emails with k9 mail in Genymotion emulator .When I try to create the account (I've tried with yahoo and mailbox account) it shows this:
          [Unrezognize Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iekMd.png)

Comment: Are date and time of the device/emulator correct?

Comment: They were not ,but I still have the same problem.I read that I can buy the certificate of SSL.Is this the only solution?

Comment: Eh what? You want a connection to the Yahoo mail server, don't you? Then you don't need anything. Or are you trying to build your own server?

Comment: No I'm not trying to build my own server.But it keeps saying Unrecognized Certificate .I can open K9 but then I have problem for ecrypting the message using Open Keychain.